# exponent rule when dividing the same exponents

Tags: exponentiation

I ran into a bit of confusion when applying the exponent rule:
$x^a/x^b = x^{a-b}$

Then when $4^x/2^x$ 
why does it equal $2^x$
if we apply the rule above then wouldn't it be:
$(4/2)^{x-x}$ ?

Thank you!

Comment: 4 and 2 are different.  Write $4^x = (2^2)^x = 2^{2x}$.  Now you have the same base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $4$ and $2$ are different, this rule does not apply !

What you can use is

$$\frac{a^x}{b^x}=\left(\frac ab\right)^x.$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

$4=2^2$ so $4^x=(2^2)^x=2^{2x}$